# AWS AccessDeniedException elastictranscoder:CreateJob

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-lambda

I'm trying to use a Lambda function to trigger an Elastic Transcoder job, but I keep getting this error message:

```
AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::xxx:assumed-role/xxxx/xxx is not authorized to perform: elastictranscoder:CreateJob on resource: arn:aws:elastictranscoder:xxxxx:pipeline/xxxxx
```

My IAM user policy covers all access requirements:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1465486106000",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:GetLogEvents",
            "logs:PutLogEvents",
            "logs:DescribeLogStreams"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:Put*",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:*MultipartUpload*",
            "s3:Get*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "2",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sns:Publish",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "3",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*Delete*",
            "s3:*Policy*",
            "sns:*Remove*",
            "sns:*Delete*",
            "sns:*Permission*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
}
```

Why am I getting the `AccessDeniedException` and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your policy to below and then try it will work

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1465486106000",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [

            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:GetLogEvents",
            "logs:PutLogEvents",
            "logs:DescribeLogStreams"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "elastictranscoder:*",
            "s3:Put*",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:*MultipartUpload*",
            "s3:Get*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "2",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sns:Publish",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "3",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*Delete*",
            "s3:*Policy*",
            "sns:*Remove*",
            "sns:*Delete*",
            "sns:*Permission*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: I suspect the elastictranscoder line needs to be in a section that applies to any resource, not to arn:aws:logs.

Comment: still getting the same error with the posted policy.. trying the suggestion now

Comment: it worked in the Sid: 1 statement! if another answer is added or this one is updated, I will accept it

Answer (score 4):

You dont need to change json by editing.
First of all detect which role you want to edit ?

```
1-) Click Permisson http://prntscr.com/j1giww 
2-) see the role name http://prntscr.com/j1gj6s 
3-) go to IAM Roles 
4-) select the roles that you see at step 2
5-) edit policy and add Transcoder Full Access ( Or selected access )
```

Comment: This helped me :)